# Stream HTTPS GET loading and parsing XML inside GZ

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services, stream, gzip

I need to process (if possible) an XML inside GZ during stream getting it from HTTPS.
If saved the resulted file is very big : 23 GB.

Right now I GET the data from HTTPS using streaming and save the file to a storage. As the Python script needs to be deployed on AWS as a Batch Job the storage is not an option. And I prefer to not using S3 service as storage.

The algorithm should be:

```
 while stream GET HTTPS in chunk:
   - get xml chunk from GZ chunk
   - process xml chunk
```

XML for example has the next structure :

```
<List>
<Property>
     <id = '123>
     <PhotoProperties>
          <Photo>
              <url = 'https://www.url.com/photo/1.jpg>
          </Photo>
      </PhotoProperties>
</Property>
<Property>...</Property>
```

I need to extract the data as a list of

```
@dataclass
class Picture:
   id: int
   url: str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.
Key is that all operations support streaming and there are libraries to do so:

- [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) for streaming the content
- [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) can be used to decompress a gzip stream
- regarding xml parsing it is key to understand that there are 2 major ways to parse an xml file:

  - **DOM parsing**: is useful when a full xml can be stored in memory. This allows easy manipulation and discovery of your xml content.
  - **SAX parsing**: is useful in case the xml cannot be stored in memory, e.g. because it is too big or because you want to start handling before reading the full stream. This is what you need in your case. [xml.parsers.expat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html) can be used for this.

I created a (well-formed) xml fragment based on your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
    <Property id = "123">
        <PhotoProperties>
            <Photo url = "https://www.url.com/photo/1.jpg"/>
        </PhotoProperties>
    </Property>
    <Property id = "456">
        <PhotoProperties>
            <Photo url = "https://www.url.com/photo/2.jpg"/>
        </PhotoProperties>
    </Property>
</List>
```

Because you do not load the full xml in memory, it is a bit more complex to parse it. You need to create handlers that get called when e.g. an xml element is opened or closed. In below example I've put these handlers in a class that keeps state in a Picture object and prints it when the  close tag is found:

```
import urllib.request
import zlib
import xml.parsers.expat
from dataclasses import dataclass

URL='https://some.url.com/pictures.xml'

@dataclass
class Picture:
   id: int
   url: str

class ParseHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.currentPicture = None

    def start_element(self, name, attrs):
        if (name=='Property'):
            self.currentPicture = Picture(attrs['id'], None)
        elif (name=='Photo'):
            self.currentPicture.url=attrs['url']

    def end_element(self, name):
        if (name=='Property'):
            print(self.currentPicture)
            self.currentPicture=None

handler = ParseHandler()

parser = xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()
parser.StartElementHandler = handler.start_element
parser.EndElementHandler = handler.end_element

decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)

with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as stream:
    for gzchunk in stream:
        xmlchunk = decompressor.decompress(gzchunk)
        parser.Parse(xmlchunk)
```